# How to highlight text on input focus?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When user clicks on input type text I want the text inside to be highlighted. I already tried on focus event and select(). It does not work. In addition I am using react.

Answer (score 2):

'

```css
input:focus, textarea:focus{
background-color: #dcdcdc;
}
```

```html
 <label>TEST</label>
 <p><input type="text" size="40"></p>
```

Test

input:focus, textarea:focus {
background-color: blue;
}'`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

I used onFocus and it works just fine:

```
<input type="text" onFocus={e => e.target.select()}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I used focus and it works all text boxes just fine.

```js
$('input[type=text]').focus(function(){  $(this).select() })
```